# NServiceBus 4 Auditing with SqlTransport

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I'm having a hard time getting auditing to work after upgrading to NSB 4 (4.6.2) and changing to SqlTransport.

I'm not seeing anything in the audit table in the NServiceBus database. From what I read, `UnicastBusConfig.ForwardReceievedMessagesTo` should still work. But it was not working. So I tried changing the config to `AuditConfig.QueueName` and there is still nothing making it to the audit queue.

I also modified the configuration to include `Configure.Features.Enable<Audit>()` (which I don't think is necessary).

Any other suggestions?

Edit: I figured out that ServiceControl is deleting messages from the audit queue. It's nice that ServiceControl is supposed to handle auditing now. But the messages appear to just be deleted from the queue and not processed elsewhere. Also, [ServiceControlURL]/api/audit just returns a 404. What's up with that?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The Service Control default config appears to delete messages from the audit queue.

Check out [this issue](https://github.com/Particular/ServiceControl/issues/333) and [this issue](https://github.com/Particular/ServiceControl/issues/183). I updated my ServiceControl config to begin forwarding messages and now it's working fine.

Also, the reason the request to ServiceControl for the audit resource returns a 404 is that there [isn't an endpoint to handle that request](https://github.com/Particular/ServiceControl/issues/344).